# Flutter: MaterialApp throws Null check operator used error

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is where I instantiate my MaterialApp:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'My New App';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        initialRoute: '/special',
        routes: {
          '/special': (context) => const SpecialPage(),
          '/another': (context) => const AnotherPage()
        });
  }
}
```

The pages are very similar.  Here is the Special page:

```
class SpecialPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpecialPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Special Stuff'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/another');
          },
          child: const Text('Special Content Goes Here'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I try to compile I get the error: *Null check operator used on a null value*.  Why?

The error message indicates the problem occurs in the construction of MaterialApp.

Comment: just remove const key-word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `const` in the `build` method of `MyApp`

Like so:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        initialRoute: '/special',
        routes: {
          '/special': (context) => const SpecialPage(),
          '/another': (context) => const AnotherPage()
        });
  }
```

Comment: OK, I had to restart the app, but it has now worked fine.  Thanks.  Can you explain what was going wrong?